# Android error "expected buildTargetsCommandComponents [...]"

Tags: android, cmake

I'm developing an Android application for simple Facial recognition.

- My Application build and run fine in emulator,
- But App can't install in real device,
- And we get Gradle error for `CMake` related task, with error-message:

> Task :engine:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':engine:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1410] D:\KAM\code\AET\AET\engine.cxx\Debug\3p465u2i\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json debug|arm64-v8a : expected **buildTargetsCommandComponents or ncnn-release-arm64-v8a.buildCommandComponents to exist**

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "release")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../distribution/${ANDROID_ABI})

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(ncnn STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ncnn PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libncnn.a)

add_library(opencv_core STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(opencv_core PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_core.so)

add_library(opencv_imgproc STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(opencv_imgproc PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_imgproc.so)

add_library(opencv_codecs STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(opencv_codecs PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_imgcodecs.so)


file(GLOB jni_srcs
        "*.cpp"
        "detection/*.cpp"
        "live/*.cpp"
    )

add_library(engine SHARED ${jni_srcs})

target_link_libraries(engine log jnigraphics ncnn opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_codecs android -static-openmp -fopenmp)
```

build.gradle(Module: engine):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version = "3.6.0"
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}


I try to find the reason but no luck. So far find only [this][1].
Any help or resource will be great for me. Thanks
```

Comment: Share your device name and model.

Comment: I tried to run multiple device [Samsung X-cover(Android -10), Samsung Z-flip(Android-12) ]

Comment: It works on your emulator because it's most likely an x86 image. However most phones use an arm processor, therefore it has to be build for that architecture. Can you provide your makefile and gradle buildfiles?

Comment: I see. I have updated my question with gradle file and Cmakelist.txt file

Answer (score 1):

I just met similar "expected buildTargetsCommandComponents ..." error log.

And like many other times, deleting the build directory and restarting IDE fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes that's the one of the solution. Thanks for adding

Answer (score -1):

first rebuild your app and then check this location

```
PROJECT PATH...\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj
```

There should be at least 4 folders for different abi's

x86  -   x64  -- arm64/v7a -- arm64/v8

if its not exist there

apply this to your build.gradle

```
abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case PROJECT PATH...\app\build\intermediates\ this path have no cmake folder. 

Also I apply abiFilters but no luck till now.